# rename multiple files in order with command prompt

Tags: command-line, command-prompt

I have some files with different names.

> Leviathan.txt,Dragon.txt and so on

I wanted to turn it into a digit begins

> 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.txt and so on

how to perform like other language by using For and function that can pass amount files in folder?

my code so far i know is dir and ren. and i stuck now.

```
ren *.txt 1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Next code snippet could work for you (save with `.bat` extension); note that `rename` command is echoed merely for debugging purposes:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /A "ii=0"
pushd "working_directory_here"
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /ON "*.txt" 2^>NUL') do (
  set /A "ii+=1"
  echo ren "%%~G" "!ii!%%~nxG"
)
popd
```

If you insist on an one-liner (launch in proper working directory):

```
cmd /E:ON /V:ON /K (@echo off^&set /A "ii=0" ^>NUL^&for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /B /ON "*.txt" 2^^^>NUL') do (set /A "ii+=1" ^>nul^&echo ren "%~G" "!ii!%~nxG"))^&exit
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`EnableDelayedExpansion`) [Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`^>`, `%%` etc.) [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming none of your existing files are already named something like n.txt, where n is a number, then simply CD to your folder, and run the following command from the command line:

```
for "tokens=1* delims=:" %A in ('dir /b *.txt^|findstr /n "^"') do @ren "%B" "%A.txt"
```

Double up the percents if you use the command within a batch script.

**EDIT**

I forgot about my [JREN.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a regular expression renaming utility. It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

JREN has a built in ability to incorporate a number into each new file name, and as an added bonus, it can left pad the number with zeros so that a DIR command lists the files in numerical order. The default numeric width is 3 digits, so files would be like "001.txt", "002.txt', ... "010.txt", ... "100.txt", etc.

```
jren "^.*" "$n+'.txt'" /j /fm *.txt
```

The /NPAD option specifies the minimum numeric width, so NTAB 1 produces no padding, which is what the original question asked for.

```
jren "^.*" "$n+'.txt'" /j /fm *.txt /npad 1
```

Since JREN is a batch script itself, you must use CALL JREN if you put the command within another batch script.

Full documentation is available from the command prompt via `jren /? | more`. My console window is configured with a large buffer, so I can scroll back to see prior output, and I don't bother with piping the help to MORE.