# Rename Files with an index (CMD)

Tags: windows, cmd

I have lots of files and I want to rename them to something like `Bild(1).jpg`, `Bild(2).jpg`, `Bild(3).jpg`, ....

I know how to rename one File in CMD:

```
ren *.* Bild(1).jpg
```

But how can I achieve this to over hundreds of files?

Comment: You want to rename hundreds of files without defining any rule which original file is going to get which new name?

Comment: Yes, the First should be namend Bild(1), the Second Bild(2) and so on.

Comment: You better write a small batch script, because it won't look pretty with a one-line cmd command.

Comment: What is "the first one"? cmd.exe and explorer.exe have different ideas about ordering files.

Comment: Its the first file the cmd.exe find.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012400/rename-multiple-files-in-order-with-command-prompt

Comment: @AntonSchrage Are you don't care what order they are named in, other than the order they appear currently in cmd..? I am guessing you already have them in a sort that works for your purposes, alphabetically.  How about this, instead of re-naming them we create hard links to them initially so that in case there is any issue with how they are being renamed you can speak to us about the order further.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but what I seem to think you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
for %%i in (*.jpg) do (
  set /a num+=1
  echo ren "%%~i" "Bild(!num!)%%~xi"
)
```

For now it simply `echo`'s the command `ren`, to actually perform the rename, you need to remove `echo` from the last line to do the renaming.

Also note, this does not recursively search through sub directories as that was not part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

@AntonSchrage Are you don't care what order they are named in, other than the order they appear currently in cmd..?

I am guessing you already have them in a sort that works for your purposes alphabetically.

Instead of `ren`aming the files we can be safer and just create Hardlinks using `MKLINK`then if there is an issue with how they are being renamed you can speak to us about the order further.

If no issue you can just delete the original files and use the hard linked files, or use the rename version of the command below.

### Create Hard Links - Directly in the `CMD` CLI Window

```
MD "%TEMP%\Hard_Links\"
SET "#="
FOR %_ IN ( "C:\Your\Path\To\Files\*.jpg" ) DO (
  CALL SET /A "#=#+1"
  CALL MKLINK /H "%TEMP%\Hard_Links\Bild(%#%).jpg" "%~f_" )
```

### Rename the Files  - Directly in the `CMD` CLI Window

```
SET "#="
FOR %_ IN ( "C:\Your\Path\To\Files\*.jpg" ) DO (
  CALL SET /A "#=#+1"
  CALL REN "%~f_" "Bild(%#%).jpg" )
```

**NOTE:**  Hardlinks look and act like separate files but are pointers to the originals, so they will not take up extra space on the disk.

You can use the hard links to inspect the file contents in whatever application/webpage/etc. and ensure they are appearing as you expect.

This way, if the order is not what you expected using the hard links you haven't lost the original naming, and can just delete the hard links.

**If you are satisfied that they are to your requirements you can delete the original files and the hard links become the filehandles permanently.**

Alternatively, you can delete the links and rename the files using the Rename version I posted above to rename them directly.

Answer (score 0):

---

May I suggest to you?

Count these files first, then loop them to rename your sequenced files,

Also, considering led by zeros ...

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

for /f %%i in ('dir /o-d /on /b "*.jpg" 2^>nul^|find "" /v /c')do set _cnt=%%i
for /f ^tokens^=* %%f in ('where ".:*.jpg"')do rename "%%~f" "Bild(!_cnt!).jpg" && set /a _cnt-=1
```

---

- `:: or, led by zero yours files::`

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

for /f %%i in ('dir /o-d /on /b "*.jpg" 2^>nul^|find "" /v /c')do set "_cnt=%%i"
for /f ^tokens^=* %%f in ('where ".:*.jpg"')do set "_led=00000!_cnt!" && (
                 rename "%%~f" "Bild(!_led:~-5!).jpg" && set /a "_cnt-=1" )
```

---

In the first loop, use dir + find /v /c to count the total number of files in the folder.

In the next loop you can rename, use _cnt decreases the _cnt variable (**`set "_cnt-=1"**), the loop itself updates the _led variable and adds 0000 to all actions by setting _led (zeros + _cnt).

Thus, you can define the number of digits to use for renaming by concatenating 00000 + _cnt.
The **`set _led=!_led:~-5!`** will take/use, only the last 5 digits to rename your file...

---

> - Or, something completely different from exposed above, and, that my english **limited** prevent me to explain to you clearly :)

---

For more information about commands, you can try getting all command help text by command line like this:

```bat
>"%temp%\all-helps.txt" (for /? & set /? & dir /? & rename /? ) & "%temp%\all-helps.txt"

rem :: Sorry about the English...
```

---

Answer (score -2):

If you know any langauge like python or PHP. You can do it by using any loop. 
Read all files from that directory and then loop on that. All files will be renamed. If you rename one file then follow the below steps.
STEPS: 
1-> Press crrl+R
2-> Type cmd Then Hit Enter
3-> Go to that path where is your file lies.  Then type this below command. your file will be rename

```
rename test.txt text1.txt
```

Comment: I know this, but how can i do this for hundred files without typing it hundred times?

Comment: do you realise that this pretty much defeats the entire purpose of a batch file to automate the renaming?